# How to get the count of all file IO system calls in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, system-calls, sysinternals

How do I get the number of all file IO calls produced within the Windows-based OS (to get it working at least on XP) for all processes? Something similar to the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), but programmatically accessible from C# (can be via C++ or C)

I don't need to know the details, just the count of all calls per second, once the number is obtained I will log it (every second) to a file, such as this one

```
50395
39581
59205
...
```

**UPDATE**
There are [some APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2010/04/18/sysinternal-s-procmon-new-improved-captures-both-system-application-events.aspx) available, but I am not too sure if I can use them for the whole OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "Realtime ETW consumer" - this isn't going to work on XP though. On XP, you can get this data, but not real-time, only after recording it then decoding the log.

Comment: tnx for the answer. How does ProcMon do it on XP?

Comment: ProcMon does it through extremely careful hacky methods in kernel mode that only someone like Mark can pull off. It's not an option for mere mortals like you and I :)

Comment: yeah it looks like mission impossible :)

Comment: If all you want to do is log it, then non-realtime ETW will work fine - you just need to post-process the traces and you'll get your file. You might also want to look into Perf Counters, might also get you this info.